# How to solve conflicts between CSS files

Tags: html, css, materialize

I have an index.html file which includes a whole bunch of css and js files. I have MaterializeCSS included as well as a css file called style.css. For some reason if I have them both included at the same time, when I create a page and use something from materialize (the tabs for instance) they don't look the way they should. Everything is initialized correctly and there are no errors anywhere, the font on the tabs is just not the one that should be there. When I tried not including style.css the tabs looked the way they should.

The problem is that I can't not include style.css because without it, the entire website looks messed up. I tried including them in a different order but that didn't fix it.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/f8NmTg3L) is style.css.

EDIT: I just tried commenting out all the `font-family` elements in style.css and everything seems to be working. I could just leave it this way however I don't think this is a very elegant solution.

Comment: Try to add the CSS files to the HTML in a different order. The last one the most important one.

Comment: You need to learn about CSS specificity: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/ Which is how the browser determines how elements get styled.

Comment: @sergiotx I tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: @sergioTx that is completely wrong - the specificity of the selectors being used is what matters.

Comment: @skyline3000 Maybe there were same selectors somewhere (shot in the dark, I know). He said he was importing the files, so he has no control about selectors.

Comment: If you are still having problems after reading skyline's recommendation, post a link and we can help you troubleshoot.

Comment: You should overwrite the font family in your materialise.css, that way , if a page relies solely on style.css, it won't break and then when you include materialise and style together, that won't break either

Answer (score 1):

my guess is that your styles.css is overriding some of the css in  Materialize.css and vice versa. You could check using the Dom explorer and see what is being overwritten. Chrome is very good for this as it crosses out the over written css shown in the picture linked below.

Once you find out what is being overwritten you could then write your own styles overwriting it again to make it look how you want.

Hope it helped :)

[overwritten styles in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paaMl.png)